# Drupal - Apache's Mod_Deflate breaks CSS

Tags: css, apache, drupal, themes, mod-deflate

We have enabled Apache's mod_deflate on our drupal site.
From that point onwards, we are noticing that CSS files aren't getting loaded properly. It doesn't happen every time. Kinda random.

Did anyone else notice this issue? If so, any suggested solutions?

Comment: Could you describe the symptom you observe and which makes you conclude the CSS files are not being loaded ? Do you by chance receive them with media type application/octet-stream ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with the [CSS Gzip module](http://drupal.org/project/css_gzip) than doing it with Apache directly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apache with mod_fastcgi?

mod_deflate sometimes breaks with apache mod_fastcgi.